# Como puedo obtener el ancho y alto de la pantalla con java?

Tags: java, java-swing

estoy intentando tomar una captura de pantalla con `Robot()` y investigando un poco encontre que podia hacerlo de esta manera

```
robotAwt.createScreenCapture
```

el problema es que el metodo **createScreenCapture** recibe un rectangle asi que supuse que podia hacer algo asi `robotAwt.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(y, x))`

rectangle recibe 2 int la altura y anchura si lo que necesito es tomar la captura de pantalla completa como obtengo estos tamaños? es decir como obtengo la altura y el ancho de la pantalla.

Comment: Prueba esto: `java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();`  El método [`getScreenSize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getScreenSize--) te da el tamaño de la ventana actual en pixeles.

Comment: Hola cedano gracias por ayudarme pero necesito obtener directamente esos dos valores de tipo int para pasarselos al constructor de Rectangle(y,x) viendo el link de referencia note que getScreenSize() devuelve un dimension hay una forma de parsearlo a lo que necesito entonces?

Comment: Sí claro. Para la altura: `java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height` y para el ancho: `java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width;`  así te devuelve los valores enteros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para conocer la resolución de la pantalla con Java te puedes apoyar del **framework AWT**. La clase que representa el **framework AWT** en general es **Toolikt**. **Toolikt** es una abstracción y permite enganchar con implementaciones nativas del framework.

Lo primero es instanciar el framework:

```
Toolkit t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
```

Una vez instanciado el framework, utilizar el método **Toolikt** para conocer la resolución de la pantalla. En concreto utilizar el método **.getScreenSize()**. Este método devolverá una clase **Dimensions**, la cual sirve para albergar las dimensiones de cualquier componente de **AWT**.

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
```

Ya solo queda acceder a las propiedades **height** y **width** de **Dimensions** para conocer la resolución de la pantalla.

```
System.out.println("Tu resolución es de " + screenSize.width + "x" + screenSize.height);
```

o

```
int ancho = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width;
int alto = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height;
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar con esto:

```
Dimension screenSize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
double h= screenSize.getHeight();
double w= screenSize.getWidth();
```

Pero no necesitas hacer esos pasos puedes hacer directamente esto:

```
Rectangle a = new Rectangle(screenSize);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Rafael peor acepto la respuesta de @SoftMolina por que me parece que contiene mucha informacion util